# nodejs-Osmosis: how to pass results to other functions?

Tags: node.js, function, variables

I found this nodejs package and I have working code with correct results. But, I don't know how to pass these results to other functions. What I want is: get some info from web page, store it in variable, pass to onesignal function and send onesignal notification (I'm using onesignal-node package).
This is my code now:

```
osmosis
.get('url')
.find('.content_body_left li')
.set('day')
.follow('a@href')
.find('table tr')
.delay(1000)
.set({
  city: 'td[2]',
  street: 'td[3]',
  time:'td[4]'
})
.data(function(document) {
   var city = document['city'];  // <== this variable I want to get
   return city;
})
var firstNotification = new OneSignal.Notification({
    contents: {
     // en: "test msg"
        en: city // <== this is where I want to put variable
    }
});
```

Problem is that I can't get `document['city'];` value out of `.data(function(document) { ... })` so I can't use it anywhere in my code.

EDIT:
I have this code also after `.data(function(document) { ... })`

```
firstNotification.setIncludedSegments(['All']);
firstNotification.setExcludedSegments(['Inactive Users']);
firstNotification.setParameter('data', {"abc": "123", "foo": "bar"});
myClient.sendNotification(firstNotification, function (err, httpResponse,data) {
   if (err) {
       console.log('Something went wrong...');
   } else {
       console.log(data, httpResponse.statusCode);
   }
});
```

So, if I put `var firstNotification = new OneSignal.Notification({ ... });` it says: "firstNotification is not defined". But if I put all that code in  `.data(function(document) { ... })` or promise, it's working. But, is there any way to keep that other half of code out of .data (or promise)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the logic to get the `city` in a Promise:

```
var promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  osmosis
  .get('url')
  .find('.content_body_left li')
  .set('day')
  .follow('a@href')
  .find('table tr')
  .delay(1000)
  .set({
    city: 'td[2]',
    street: 'td[3]',
    time:'td[4]'
  })
  .data(function(document) {
     var city = document['city'];  // <== this variable I want to get
     resolve(city);
  })
});


promise.then(city => {
  var firstNotification = new OneSignal.Notification({
    contents: {
     // en: "test msg"
        en: city // <== this is where I want to put variable
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: This is working but I have to warp another half of onesignal code in it. See my EDIT.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with putting the other half in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
osmosis
.get('url')
.find('.content_body_left li')
.set('day')
.follow('a@href')
.find('table tr')
.delay(1000)
.set({
  city: 'td[2]',
  street: 'td[3]',
  time:'td[4]'
})
.data(function(document) {
   var firstNotification = new OneSignal.Notification({
        contents: {
            // en: "test msg"
            en: document.city // <== this is where I want to put variable
        }
   });
})
```